# Google form script to send email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm having some issues regarding this script for sending an email after the submit of google form.

So, when I run my code I receive this error message: **ReferenceError: getValues is not defined at onFormSubmit**

Below you can find the script

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] onFormSubmit");
  
  sendEmail(e.range);
}

function sendEmail(range) {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] sendEmail");

  // FETCH SPREADSHEET //
  var values = range.getValues();
  var row = values[0];

  // EXTRACT VALUES //
  var DateRequest = values[0]
  var TypeRequest = values[1]
  var StartDate = values[2]
  var EndDate = values[3]
  var Observation = values[4]
  var TLemail = values[5]

  // CLEAN VARIABLES //
  if (Observation.length == 0) Explain = "None";
  
  // PREPARE EMAIL //
  var emailRecipients = +TLemail+"@google.com";
  var emailSubject = TypeRequest;
  var emailBody = "<h3>Vacation Request:</h3><hr /> \
  <p> \
  <strong>Type or request:</strong><br /> \
  "+TypeRequest+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>Date of Request:</strong><br /> \
  "+DateRequest+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>Start Date:</strong><br /> \
  "+StartDate+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>End Data:</strong><br /> \
  "+EndDate+" \
  </p><p> \
  <strong>Aditional comment:</strong><br /> \
  "+Observation+" \
  </p><p> \
  </p>";


  // SEND EMAIL //
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emailRecipients,
  subject: emailSubject,
  htmlBody: emailBody
 });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You did not define `range` nowhere in your code

- Either you define it manually
- Or, you make usage of the [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) the trigger `onFormSubmit` provides

One option would be to use the event object `range`:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var values = e.range.getValues();
```

which would be equivalent to

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  var values = event.range.getValues();
```

or

```
function onFormSubmit(hello) {
  var values = hello.range.getValues();
```

- **Or, much easier, you directly retrieve `e.values`**

So:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.values;
  var DateRequest = values[0];
  var TypeRequest = values[1];
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ziganotschka!! The last one is really easier, but now Im getting an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValues' of undefined**, I don't know if I need to set something on the triggers. Or the name of the function should have the same name as the google form?

Comment: Sorry, I had  a typing mistake, just corrected it. You can consult the correct names of all the event objects [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events). Yes, you do need to set-up a trigger manually, since onFormSubmit is an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: As a consequence, you cannot test the code including event objects manually, it will only work without error when it is run by the trigger.

Comment: Got it!! I'm gonna take a look on it, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry again to bother!!! I already update using **var values = e.values;**

And set up the triggers, but I still get en erro, I really do know why, the error now is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined**

Comment: As mentioned above-you will get this error if you try to run a function with event objects manually, but the script will work correctly on trigger.

Comment: Got it! On Monday I try again to see if works to send the email, Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Hey dude, thanks again for the help but I still fail on the script getting error. But I really appreciate for your time spent with me, I stil have the same **TypeError**

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: It run automatically when I submit my form, but I receive an email saying **Script function not found: sendEmail**

Im gonna check this again later on using my personal laptop and take a look if works, cause on the work computer isnt working

Comment: Do you have a function called `sendEmail`? Please update your question by adding  your new code

Comment: I updated with the original script, I think it will help more to find the problem! And thanks again.

Comment: Very important: It should be `function` and not `Function`. Also, which of the two functions did you bind to the installed onFormSubmit trigger?

Comment: Great, I already fixed.

For the Trigger, I put
Function to run - **onFormSubmit** // 
Event source - **From form** //
Event type - **On form submit**

Comment: Then it should run `function sendEmail(range)` correctly and if you get errors - they are related to the content of the function (which goes beyond your original question). To troubleshoot, you should go to `View->Executions`, click on the last execution and see why it failed (if it did). The Stackdriver logs indicate you the error and the line in which it occurred.

Comment: now my error is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValues' of undefined at sendEmail**

But I have a question, I'm writing this script directly inside the google form part, is this make some difference on the script?

Comment: It makes a huge difference. Because the trigger `Form submit` for `Forms` does NOT have an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) `range`, only `Form submit` for `Sheets` does! So, be careful.

Comment: Got it, I'm gonna try outside the form and see if runs.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var values = range.getValues();
```

with

```
var values = e.range.getValues();
```

Comment: Hello Amit, thanks for the reply, I replaced but now I get en erro with **ReferenceError: erange is not defined**

Comment: Sorry it is e.range

Comment: its okay Amir!!! I already change but not Im getting another error hahaha **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValues' of undefined**, I don't know if I need to set something on the triggers